# Not getting metavalue

Tags: wp-query

I want to get meta value through meta key.

Here is my code:

```
$sqlMonth = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT meta_value FROM wp_usermeta WHERE user_id = " . $user_ID . " AND meta_key = 'month'"));
$sqlYear = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT meta_value FROM wp_usermeta WHERE user_id = " . $user_ID . " AND meta_key = 'year'"));

$userMonth = $sqlMonth['meta_value'];
$userYear = $sqlYear['meta_value'];

echo $userMonth;
echo $userYear;
```

I got user month from above code. MY problem is I m not getting user year. In DB year value is saved.

Kindly advice me any solution.

Comment: If the answer was helpful to you, then consider accepting it. See »[What should I do when someone answers my question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)?« and/or »[Why is voting important](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote)?«, more information about the [wordpress.se] model is available at the [help].

Answer (score 1):

The `mysql_*()` functions won't work after *WP 3.9*, so don't use them. See Make WordPress Core entry [MySQL in WordPress 3.9](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2014/04/07/mysql-in-wordpress-3-9/). It is adviced to use `$wpdb` methods instead - if necessary.

In your case - as far as I can tell - it isn't necessary at all. You can use the relevant API functions for *User Meta* data, namely, regarding your code, [`get_user_meta()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_user_meta).

Using available API functions makes your life as developer much easier, in terms of maintainability of your code. So I strongly advice it, whenever you can.